# Why does modulus return these values?

Tags: c

5%5 is 0

5%4 is 1

5%3 is 2

5%2 is 1

5%1 is 0

Why is that? From my understanding modulus just prints out whether or not it has a remainder but I'm apparently wrong here.

also 5%10 prints out 5, and "%10" seems to consistently print out the last number of any value. 123%10 is 3 for some reason.

What's the deal here?

```
x = 5%2;
y = 123%10;
```

Comment: What do you think the result should be in each case? What is the remainder when you divide 5 by 5? It divides once and the remainder is `0` because it divides exactly.

Comment: There is no remainder for that but 5/2 is 2.5. Where does C get a 1 from in that case?

Comment: Have you tried to google it, before asking in SO?

Comment: The `%` operator is doing **integer division**. Divide 5 by 2, you get 2 remainder 1. This is primary school stuff.

Comment: @qwertyuiop123456789 In primary school, before you learn about the decimal point and stuff, 5/2 is 2, but 1 remains.

Comment: It is no accident that `% 10` always gives the last digit, when you use decimal numbers.

Comment: I have never heard of remainders before and I don't understand the concept. All math you use in highschool involves decimals, what purpose does this completely random number even serve?

Comment: As you have discovered, you can use it to extract the last digit of a decimal number, with a high degree of reliablilty that the same answer results each time. You might need the individual digits to, say, put on a display device which handles single digits.

Comment: @glglgl is it possible you can explain the purpose of this? Google says it's the amount left over after division but it literally isn't considering decimals exist. I do not understand this concept in the slightest.

Comment: There's integer division, and division that results in decimals. 10 / 3 is either 3.333..., or 3 remainder 1 depending on what type of division you're doing. Surely you learned to do long division on paper when you were in school? That doesn't use decimals; that gives you a remainder.

Comment: Please read the duplicate question, which has at least a dozen answers. I hope you can get a satisfactory understanding from it.

Comment: @qwertyuiop123456789 *I do not understand this concept in the slightest.* – Let's assume it's 22:00 ... what hour will the clock show in 4 hours from now? `(22 + 4) % 24 = 2` ... in 28 hours? `(22 + 28) % 24 = 2` ...

Comment: @qwertyuiop123456789 If you have 7 apples and 3 children, and you divide the apples among the children, each gets 2, and you keep (remain) 1. So 7/3, in integer division, is 2, with a remainder of 1. If you divide the one apple as well, eachh gets another ⅓ apple, so the "non-integer" result (which involves cutting an apple) is 2⅓.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From my understanding modulus just prints out whether or not it has a remainder but I'm apparently wrong here.

You are right, but only in so far as you recognize that you are wrong.

You think too complicated: modulus is not the decision if there is a remainder or not, but it just *is* the remainder. 0 thus means "no reminder", and so the modulo operation can be used in a boolean context.

This obviously leaves opwn what is meant by "division remainder".

Division per se is the question "If I have X objects and distribute it to Y targets, how many will each recipient get?"

The result differs whenther or nit I can divide a single object.

Assume I have 25 € (or $ or whatever) and want to distribute them to 4 people. Then we all assume that each is entitled to 6,25 €. But what happens if I oby have 1 € coins? Then I can distribute only 6 € to each, and I will have 1 € left which cannot be distributed in a fair way.

So this shows the two possible results of 25 / 4:

- In floating point division, I get 6.25, and the reverse operation 6.25 * 4 gets 25 again, the original value.
- In integer division, I get 6. But the reverse operation 6 * 4 doesn't get 25, but 24, so I have a remainder of 1.

On other words: The remainder of `x / y` is the result of `x - (x / y) * y`.

If any doubts are still open, Wikipedia has a lemma about the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) as well.

Comment: The problem here is that there is apparently a concept of "remainder" that I never learned in school(seemingly in elementary) and is literally never used again in middle or highschool. I don't even see the purpose of this and now trying to figure out how to program with it makes it seem even more confusing.